# having bracket in front of an item

Tags: lists

I want to have an enumerate item which is surrounded by brackets. Something like this

1. [Initialization]

but surrounding text with [ and ] makes it center aligned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know why that would center it, but you really should write

```
\item\relax[Initialization]
```

in order for LaTeX not to think you have an optional argument for `\item`.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what you mean by centered, but `[..]` following an `\item` is interpreted as optional parameter to the `\item`.

You could use `\item{} [Initialization]`.

It should not be centered. Unless you put `\[` and `\]` around it, which makes it a math formula and the letters are interpreted as variables and not text.